# Trying To Do a Find and Replace to Parts of a 200 line List of Tuples - Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

A sample of both cases popping up. Below. In a long list my "e"s have turned into "\xe9" and "\xe8" because of the little comma's over "e"s from French. I'd like to seamlessly turn these "\xe8" things back into "e"s.
I see there's a module(?) called Unidecode. Never used it. Is it the most Pythonic way to deal with this?

These are tuples inside a list.
Example of a part of the list...

```
(u'Caf\xe9 Society', 70)
(u'Oddball and the Penguins (Oddball)', 86)
(u'Antarctica: Ice & Sky (La glace et le ciel)', 95)
(u"Reset (Rel\xe8ve: Histoire d'une cr\xe9ation)", 75)
```

I've tried...

```
list3 = ['e' if x=='/ex9' else x for x in list2]
```

This doesn't give me an error. It just doesn't do anything.

I'll put up my entire code because I don't quite know how to replicate this on a small scale. It pulls a few hundred movie titles and scores from RottenTomatoes.com.

```
import requests

r3 = requests.get('https://www.rottentomatoes.com/api/private/v2.0/browse?page=1&limit=330&type=dvd-all&services=amazon%3Bamazon_prime%3Bfandango_now%3Bhbo_go%3Bitunes%3Bnetflix_iw%3Bvudu&sortBy=release')


movies = []
data = r3.json()
for result in data["results"]:
    movies.append((result["title"], result["tomatoScore"]))



list2 = [i for i in movies if i[1] >=60]


list3 = ['e' if x=='/ex9' else x for x in list2]

for i in list3:
    print i
```

Comment: Try ```s.replace(chr(232), 'e')``` ??  Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7. What's 232? Specifically for the e with the french thing over it?. I'm somewhat new to Python so I'm not really sure where to put
    s.replace(chr(232), 'e')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that's the result you got from `print`, and I think you misunderstand how it works in python. **You don't need to replace anything, they're exactly the characters they are, just the "escaped version"**.

Try to do this:

```
for movie in movies:
    print movie[0], movie[1]
    print movie
```

And the result:

```
Café Society 70
(u'Caf\xe9 Society', 70)
Reset (Relève: Histoire d'une création) 75
(u"Reset (Rel\xe8ve: Histoire d'une cr\xe9ation)", 75)
```

When you print a string, you get the output of the `__str__` method of the object, and actually the `__str__` method of a list is different, it creates a string by using the `__repr__` method of each object, that's why you see different result on your console.

Comment: I see. That's good to know. I was printing just the movie titles alone with this code... 
list3 = [str(i[0]) for i in list2]

for i in list3:
 print i
What you showed me is much better. There was no problem aside from the bad code. Though I would still like to replace them with regular 'e's. I think I can search documentation for the Unidecode module